# MySQL sum up numbers in a relational database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm making a web application to make customers order items for anything. For that I've made  a MySQL database which has the following tables:

- `customers`
- `orders`
- `order-items`
- `products`

In the `customers` table is all the information about the person such as:

- The customer ID, for the primary key and auto increment (id)
- The first name (first_name)
- The last name (last_name)
- The email address (email_adress)
- Information about the customer (customer_info)

**Example:**

[image]

In the `orders` table is all the specific information about it such as:

- The order ID, for the primary key and auto increment (id)
- Which customer ordered it, linked with `id` field from the `customers` table (customer_id)
- Order information (order_info)
- The location where the order needs to go to (location)
- When the order was created (created)

**Example:**

[image]

In the `order-items` table are all the items which every customer ordered, this is being linked by the `order-id` from the previous table.

- The ID, for primary key and auto increment, not used for any relation (id)
- The order ID, used for which product is for which order. This is linked with the `id` field from the `orders` table (order_id)
- The product ID, this is used for what product they ordered, this is linked with the id field from the `products` table. (product_id)
- The amount of this product they ordered (quantity)

**Example:**

[image]

In the `products` table is all the information about the products:

- The ID, for primary key and auto incrementing, This is linked with the `product_id` field from the `order_items` table (id)
- The name of the product (name)
- The description of the product (description)
- The price of the product (price)

**Example:**

[image]

**The problem**

Bob ordered `product_id` 2, times 3. Which is the sandwich with beef with the price of `2.50`, which we have to multiply by 3 because it has been ordered 3 times. Which is `7.50`

Bob also ordered `product_id` 3, times 5. Which is the sandwich with chicken with the price of `3.00`, which we have to multiply by 5 because it has been ordered 5 times. Which comes out on `15.00`

Now I need to sum these up. Which is `15.00 + 7.50 = 22.50`

**The question**

How do I get the `product_id` linked with the actual price of the `product_id`? which I can then multiply by the quantity.

And then sum up all those values with the same `order_id`

For the first order we get product 2 (Quantity 3) and product 3 (Quantity 5), which should add 2.50*3 + 3.00*5 = 22.50

Comment: Your design is at risk of misreporting past sales when  price change occurs.  However, to solve this problem can you show an expected output given teh sample provided?

Comment: @xQbert What do you mean about when the price changes? It still makes the same calculation right? The expected output of a total price wich the customer should have pay would be that 22.50 then right?

Comment: So today's price for bob's order totals 15.00+7.50 for 22.50.  Tomorrow the prices go up.  3 and 3.50 respectively so 7.50 becomes 9 and 15 becomes 5*3.5=17.50 so the total is for today's order 26.50.  But what was yesterday's total again (since we do not seem to be storing the price/total on the order or sale)  oh yeah it's 26.50 too.. because that's what the price table says and what the calculation evaluates to.  However, if this isn't a concern then what you're trying to do is a sum of a product

Comment: It still makes the same calculation right?.. `based on current prices yes, but based on what the price was yesterday then no`  The expected output of a total price wich the customer should have pay would be that 22.50 then right? Yes, but if price change today to a higher amount and you wanted to know what was paid yesterday, how would you figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked, "
**How do i get the product_id linked with the actual price of the product_id? Which i can then multiply by the quantity... And then sum up all those values with the same order_id.**"

Like this:

```
SELECT OI.Order_ID, Sum(OI.Quantity * P.Price) Total_Price
FROM `order-items` OI
INNER JOIN Products P
 on OI.Products_Id = P.ID
GROUP BY OI.Order_ID
```

Expected output for sample data in question:

```
ORDER_ID Total_price
1        22.50
```

This is why I asked about sample Output.  I'm not sure what columns you were trying to return so I returned just the sum total for each order.

Now what this says
Return a row for each order showing the order ID and the total_price which is the sum of (quantity ordered * price all lines for that order.

This is accomplished by looking at the order-items table (in back tic's because I'm not sure if mySQL like's dashes (-) in names.).  Joining these tables based on the product_Id between the ordered items table and the price table. and then group the results by the ordered item allowing the sum to aggregate all the rows for an order times the price of the item on that line of the order together.

Comment: can you please be more clear with all the letters and such? I dont get any of it... :(

Comment: OI is a table alias for Order-items. P is a table alias for Productions

Comment: Do i have to make new tables for this query to execute in my current database? Because theres no quantity field in my order items table.

Comment: ... then your orinal post is missleading. it states, "In the order-items table are all the items wich every customer ordered, this is being linked by the order-id from the previous table.

The ID, for primary key and auto increment, not used for any relation (id)
The order ID, used for wich product is for wich order. This is linked with the id field from the orders table (order_id)
The product ID, this is used for what product they ordered, this is linked with the id field from the products table. (product_id)
`The amount of this product they ordered (quantity)`

Comment: You're right about the database, the numbers wont be correct anymore when i change the prices. Is it possible to have a field in my `orders` table wich automaticly generates the current total price? that would be better i think.

Comment: Either include price on the order and set it at the time the order is placed, or put dates on price table and order detail table and join back using dates.  Adding price info to order table is simpler but if you ever have to reprocess an order after a price change for the point in time in the past, you will not be able to.  Start and end dates/times on prices as prices change is the safest long term.

Answer (score 1):

You can build an intermediate table that has the totals for each order, then JOIN that with the orders table to get the customerID of that order, which you join with customers to get the customer name

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, Totals.Order_ID, Totals.NetCost
FROM (SELECT OI.order_id, SUM(OI.quantity * P.price) as NetCost 
        FROM orderitems as OI INNER JOIN products as P ON OI.products_id = P.id
        GROUP BY OI.order_id
    ) as Totals
    INNER JOIN orders as O on O.ID = Totals.order_id
    INNER JOIN customers as C on C.ID = O.customer_id
```

And the problem @xQbert is talking about is that if your customer places an order on Monday, you raise your price on Tuesday, and run this report on Wed, the report will show a total different from what the customer saw when he approved the order. A better design would be to store orderprice in orderitem, or at least the ordertotal in orders so subsequent price changes don't affect historic orders. The former is better in case a customer wants a refund on one item.

EDIT: I mean the problem @xQbert mentions in his comment, his answer came in ahead of mine but I missed it on the refresh

EDIT 2: More explanation, as requested by @Bas

It's easiest to think of this query from the inside and work outward, so let me start with getting the prices of items.
I want to link an item in orderitem with it's price, so JOIN orderitem (I give it an alias of OI) to products (I give an alias of P) on the product ID. Product ID is called products_id in OrderItem, but just ID in products.

Once I have that, I can multiply the price from Products by the quantity in OrderItems to get a cost for just that item

Because I want the total of everything for each order, I use a GROUP BY clause on this sub query, with the thing I'm grouping by being order_id. With a GROUP BY, you usually take the field or fields you are grouping by, and some "aggregate" fields where you take the sum, or max, or average, or whatever of them, and it's the sum or whatever for all rows that are in the same group.

So at this point we have defined the query inside the parenthesis. I named that Totals, and it acts just like a real table, but it goes away when your query is over.

The next step is to combine this "totals" table with your orders table so we can look up the customer ID, and then combine it with Customers so we can look up the customer name. I used aliases for Customer and Orders (C and O respectively), but they are not necessary. In fact, this could be rewritten most if not all of the aliases. I think it makes it more readable, but if they confuse you, you could use the following instead, it's the same. I think Totals is necessary, but maybe not even that.

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Totals.Order_ID, Totals.NetCost
FROM (SELECT order_id, SUM(quantity * price) as NetCost 
        FROM orderitems INNER JOIN products ON products_id = products.id
        GROUP BY order_id
    ) as Totals
    INNER JOIN orders on orders.ID = Totals.order_id
    INNER JOIN customers on customers.ID = orders.customer_id
```

Hopefully this is clear, but if not, leave more comments and I'll further explain tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for this, but can you please be more clear with all the letters you are using? I dont get any of it...